# The latest chrono 0.4 crate uses time 0.1 which has a potential segfault - how to fix?

Tags: rust, rust-chrono, tokio-postgres, r2d2

I'm writing an app in Rust that uses a PostgreSQL client connection pool with Chrono (0.4.22) features for date time calculations. So my `Cargo.toml` has these lines:

```
[dependencies]
postgres = {version = "0.19", features = ["with-chrono-0_4"]}
chrono = "0.4"
chrono-tz = "0.6"
```

But after running `cargo audit` it seems <strike>Cargo</strike> Chrono is using and old version (0.1.44) of the time crate, causing a vulnerability report on RUSTSEC-2020-0071:

```
# cargo audit
    Fetching advisory database from `https://github.com/RustSec/advisory-db.git`
      Loaded 458 security advisories (from /root/.cargo/advisory-db)
    Updating crates.io index
    Scanning Cargo.lock for vulnerabilities (138 crate dependencies)
Crate:     time
Version:   0.1.44
Title:     Potential segfault in the time crate
Date:      2020-11-18
ID:        RUSTSEC-2020-0071
URL:       https://rustsec.org/advisories/RUSTSEC-2020-0071
Solution:  Upgrade to >=0.2.23
```

According to the URL, the severity scores a CVSS score of 6.2 - MEDIUM.
The issue is discussed on GitHub: https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/602

*"Due to compatibility reasons, this release does not yet remove the time 0.1
dependency, though chrono 0.4.20 does not depend on the vulnerable parts of the time 0.1.x versions. In a future 0.5 release, we will remove the time dependency."*

Does this mean I can safely ignore this particular output of `cargo audit` ?

UPDATE: I ran `cargo update` and `chrono` is at version 0.4.22, it is still using `time` version 0.1.44. I want to assume that the GitHub quote is completely valid and it should be all I need when I send this info in an audit report.

Comment: I'd say yes, as this is pretty much what I read from your quote.

Comment: I guess you mean that *chrono* is using an old version? Not cargo?

Comment: Try `cargo update` to update the version of `time` in your `Cargo.lock`

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I want to be really sure because of an audit report on which I need to explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the default feature `oldtime` of `chrono` in `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
chrono = { version = "0.4.22", default-features = false }
```

Comment: But don't forget to re-add the other default features like `alloc` and `std`. Or wait for the next release of chrono, where [the `oldtime` feature has been removed](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/commit/4c351b1e720a30a6e32068fe386293b36d0e86fd).

Comment: Based on the URL from @Jmb, I came up with this line: `chrono = { version = "0.4", default-features = false, alloc = [], libc = [], std = [], clock = ["std", "winapi", "iana-time-zone"], wasmbind = ["wasm-bindgen", "js-sys"], unstable-locales = ["pure-rust-locales", "alloc"], __internal_bench = ["criterion"], __doctest = [] }`. Then I ran `cargo update`. Now the output of `cargo audit` is OK.

Comment: All this does is masquerade the problem. `chrono` has the **exact** same vulnerability.